# How to do google signin in an android application

Tags: android, google-authentication

I have API key of the server, sender id and package name.

How do I use these details to have a google login in my android application.

Please tell stepwise procedure of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pressume you are talking about Gmail, If so, take a look at the following link.If you have any further problems, ask about them.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android

Good luck :)